# Match from pattern to end of file in bash

Tags: regex, bash, eof

I have been trying to figure out how to use `grep` in a bash script to match from a pattern to the end of the file.  The file is not always the same number of lines each time and is not always `[A-Za-z0-9]`.  I'm trying to migrate from a flat-file based catalog to a database.

File excerpt:

```
First, Last: Doe, John
ID: xxxxxxxx
...

Case Notes:

This "person" does not exist!  
Please do not add him. 
Thanks.
```

I need to grab everything from `Case Notes:` to the end of file.  I can't seem to find anything to help out there as there isn't an actual EOF character.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `awk` script might be easier:

```
awk '/^Case Notes:$/ { matched = 1 } matched'
```

Or if you don't want to see the `Case notes:` string itself, reverse it:

```
awk 'matched; /^Case Notes:$/ { matched = 1 }'
```

Comment: Thanks.  That almost did it.  I had to modify it to be:  awk '/^Case Notes:.*$/ { matched = 1 } matched { print }'   But it worked a treat!  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

idiomatic `awk` solution would be

```
awk '/^Case Notes:$/,0'
```

prints from pattern (inclusive) to end of file.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n '/^Case notes:/,$p' file >newfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Few years late but you could use

```
more +"Case notes:" file
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `bash` can do it

```
declare -i tf=0
while read -r line
do
   case "$line" in
     *"Case notes"* ) tf=1;
   esac
   [[ $tf -eq 1 ]] && echo "$line"
done < file
```